# appendChild within addEventListener not working after first application

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, addeventlistener, appendchild

I have a webpage where it will have anywhere from 1 to N (default 3 and max 7) swapping div elements—referred to as "Sessions"—and upon selecting one, the others should disappear (not be hidden), i.e., the selected Session should take the place of the prior one. There is a function that allows for the user to swap between the divs, and that function is called upon when the page is loaded:

```
function generarSteps() {
    var numSteps = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("switch_" + i).checked == true) {
            numSteps = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    $('#num_sesiones').html('');

    stepsString = "";
    for (let j = 1; j <= numSteps; j++) {
        stepsString += '' +
            '<div class="uc-step" id="sesion_bubble_' + j + '">' +
            '<div class="uc-step_head">' +
            '<div class="uc-step_line"></div>' +
            '<div class="uc-step_count" onclick="selectSesion(' + j + ')"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="uc-step_info">' +
            '<div class="p-size--sm text-weight--bold">Sesión ' + j + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
    }

    $('#num_sesiones').append(stepsString);
    selectSesion(1);
}
```

selectSesion: (partial, only the part that's leading the problem)

```
function selectSesion(sesion) {
    $('#materiales').empty();

    materialesString = "" +

        '<div class="p-16" style="height: 300px;">' +

        '<div class="row mx-0" style="height: 156px">' +

        '<div class="my-auto" style="width: 25%;">' +
        '<div id="docs_existentes_' + (sesion - 1).toString() + '" class="uc-form-group m-0 py-16">' +
        '<input id="myInput_' + sesion + '" type="text" class="uc-input-style doc_input mr-16" style="max-width: 255px;" placeholder="Seleccione...">' +
        '</div>' +

        '<div id="doc_nuevo_' + (sesion - 1).toString() + '"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id="docs_selec_' + (sesion - 1).toString() + '" class="uc-card" style="width: 75%; background-color: #F6F6F6"></div>' +

        '</div>' +

        '</div>';

    $('#materiales').append(materialesString);

    documentosDropdown(sesion - 1);
    documentosSeleccionados(sesion - 1);
}
```

documentosDropdown:

```
function documentosDropdown(num_sesion) {
    docs = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < documentos[num_sesion].length; j++) {
        if (documentos[num_sesion][j].SELECCIONADO != 1) {
            docs.push(documentos[num_sesion][j].NOM_ARCHIVO);
        }
    }

    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput_" + (num_sesion + 1).toString()), docs, num_sesion);
}
```

Here in autocomplete is where the error is taking place:

```
function autocomplete(inp, arr, num_sesion) {
    var currentFocus;

    // for (var j = 1 ; j <= 7 ; j++) {
    //  $('#myInput_' + j).unbind('click');
    //  $('#myInput_' + j).unbind('input');
    // }

    inp.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
    inp.addEventListener("input", handler, false);

    function handler() {
        alpha;
        beta;
        var i;
        var val = this.value;

        closeAllLists();
        currentFocus = -1;

        alpha = document.createElement("div");
        // document.getElementById("myInput_" + (num_sesion + 1).toString()).parentNode.appendChild(alpha);
        this.parentNode.appendChild(alpha);

        alpha.setAttribute("id", "myInput_" + (num_sesion + 1).toString() + "_autocomplete-list");
        alpha.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items mr-16");
        alpha.style.maxHeight = "225px";
        alpha.style.overflowY = "auto";
        alpha.style.top = "61px";

        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var indexOf = arr[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase());

            if (indexOf > -1) {
                beta = document.createElement("div");

                beta.innerHTML = arr[i].substr(0, indexOf) + "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(indexOf, val.length) + "</strong>" + arr[i].substr(val.length + indexOf);
                beta.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                alpha.appendChild(beta);

                beta.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    selectDocumento(this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value, num_sesion);
                    inp.value = "";
                    closeAllLists();
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    });
}
```

When the page is loaded for the first time, selectSesion(1) (or any session number I place in there) loads and the drop down appears as normal when the input is click on or whenever I write anything within it. But when I click on one of the other elements that houses the selectSesion(n) values, clicking the input will no longer bring the dropdown up, even though it will appear whenever I write within the input element.

Just to test, I declared the alpha variable outside the **autocomplete** function and it shows that alpha is indeed created and even filled with the beta div elements, but it itself is never appended to the input element's parent node, only when it's either the original dropdown from the first selectSesion(1) or whenever I write in the input element.

I'm guessing it has to do with javascript's asynchronous nature, but I'm fairly new to javascript so I can't determine what would be needed in order to have that child append to the input's parent node.

In short:

- Session 1 is selected upon page load
- clicking or typing in the input with id = myInput_1 appends a div element that works as its dropdown below it
- clicking on another selectSesion(n) button generates its corresponding input with id = myInput_n
- clicking on the input element creates the div element that should have been appended to the input element's parent node, but never appends it
- typing in the input element **does** however append said div element

I want it to always append the div element, whether it be a click or input on the input element. Sorry for the extremely long post, but it's long sequence of events before getting to the problem at hand.

Worst case scenario, I'd like to know if there'd be a way to simulate an input in that input element and then erase it, in order to at least activate the "input" event, which as I stated before, works fine.

Comment: If we could see the relevant HTML and CSS, it would be easier to recreate the project and do some testing. Or if you could link to the webpage, that could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the error was a problem produced by tunnel vision. The thing is, I based my function off of the w3schools autocomplete [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp), in which the autocomplete function only activates when typing and not clicking on the input element.

Their autocomplete function even adds a click event listener to the entire document in which it will close the simulated dropdown elements, which ends up conflicting with the click function for just the input element, causing the issue.

Basically I've got to change

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
});
```

in the autocomplete function to

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("doc_input")[0] != e.target) {
        closeAllLists(e.target);
    }
});
```